# Movie where a woman tries to find the murderer of her brother? Dark setting, sort of redneck characters

Tags: identify-this-movie, thriller, mystery

So, protagonist is woman (possibly blonde) whos been out of touch with her brother for a long time.

I think she discovers he's dissapeared. When she goes to track him down she finds out he's been hanging out with some redneck gangster types. Follows his story to some blown up meth shed or something.

She suspects hes been murdered though, and actually finds his body in a swamp. After a while, she gets beaten up by a gang outside a barn (asking too many questions).

The whole thing closes with her other brother (I think) in a car with her, he admits hes found out who the killer is, and it fades out as he says he's going to kill him.

Comment: That's pretty much *Winter's Bone*, but it's her father, not her brother.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're describing the powerful [Winter's Bone](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1399683/combined) from 2010 with Jennifer Lawrence, although it's not her brother missing but rather her dad.

> With an absent father and a withdrawn and depressed mother, 17 year-old Ree Dolly keeps her family together in a dirt poor rural area. She's taken aback however when the local Sheriff tells her that her father put up their house as collateral for his bail and unless he shows up for his trial in a week's time, they will lose it all. She knows her father is involved in the local drug trade and manufactures crystal meth, but everywhere she goes the message is the same: stay out of it and stop poking your nose in other people's business. She refuses to listen, even after her father's brother, Teardrop, tells her he's probably been killed. She pushes on, putting her own life in danger, for the sake of her family until the truth, or enough of it, is revealed.

The scenes you mentioned were there. The film was nominated for 4 Oscars. Here's the trailer: